# TightVNC Viewer (on Windows) gets gray screen when connecting to Ubuntu TightVNC Server (Ubuntu Desktop)

Tags: vnc

New to using Linux and trying to set this up so that I can remote in to my Ubuntu Desktop machine, which I'm using to host game servers. Currently it does successfully connect, but the viewer only displays a blank gray screen.
My xstartup file contains this:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

EDIT: I've messed with this file a bunch (set it back to default, tried several setups I found googling, etc.) and switched from the "Ubuntu" option in login to "xorg" which a friend suggested, but still no luck...
Also see comment for system information.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 64 bit, GNOME 42.0 and Wayland